# Validation of the password field and the confirm password field

Tags: javascript

Good night!
I'm developing a project for study and I really wanted to do the validation of the password field and the validation of the confirmSenha field. The idea is that when the user enters a different password, a message is returned saying that the passwords do not match. Below is the scope of my code.

```
function validarPasswordConfirm(password, confirmPassword) {

  var typedpassword = document.getElementsByName('password').value;
  var confirmTypedPassword = document.getElementsByName('passwordConfirm').value;

  if(typedpassword !== confirmTypedPassword) {
    return { value: false, text: 'Passwords are not the same.' }
  } else {
    return { value: true, text: '' }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to validate the password field with the confirmpassword field

Comment: Try using '!=' not '!=='

Answer (score 2):

The function getElementsByName returns an array, so you can't access the value property like that.

I recommend use getElementById instead.

Comment: Ja Also pays to consol.log("things" ) in true and false statements to make debugging easier

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few problems with your code.

---

Firstly, `var` is not used anymore ([see why](https://dev.to/mindninjax/stop-using-var-for-declaring-variables-2p3a)). You should use an alternative.

Alternatives for `var` are below.

1. `let` - Use this for variables that can be changed.
2. `const` - Use this for variables that cannot be changed (constant).

---

Secondly, `getElementsByName()` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which is an iterable (like an `array`). This means that `.value` is `undefined` in a `NodeList`.

To fix it, change your code to below.

```js
const typedPassword = document.querySelector("#password").value;
const confirmTypedPassword = document.querySelector("#passwordConfirm").value;
```

Comment: var is not deprecated. its just let has better memory scope .The main difference between let and var is that scope of a variable defined with let is limited to the block in which it is declared while variable declared with var has the global scope.